# TSQL Create table inside case statement

Tags: t-sql, case, create-table

The code below tries to use case condition to create a table or another. What would be the sql way to express that?

```
DECLARE @tmp VARCHAR(255)

SET @tmp = 'A'

SELECT CASE @tmp
WHEN 'A' THEN CREATE TABLE #Hello (ID Int, Hello varchar)
WHEN 'B' THEN CREATE TABLE #Goodbye (ID Int, Goodby varchar)
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement, simply use [IF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/control-of-flow?view=sql-server-2017), since inside the `CASE` statement you cannot control the flow of execution of TSQL Statements or use DDL statements.

As per @ Zohar Peled's comment, I am adding an arbitrary length to the `varchar` fields, since they had been declared without any:

```
DECLARE @tmp VARCHAR(255)

SET @tmp = 'A'
IF @tmp = 'A'  
BEGIN 
 --PRINT 'Creating table #Hello'
 CREATE TABLE #Hello (ID Int, Hello varchar(128))
END
ELSE
IF @tmp = 'B'
BEGIN
 --PRINT 'Creating table #Goodbye'
 CREATE TABLE #Goodbye (ID Int, Goodby varchar(128))
END
```

Comment: Two things keeping me from upvoting this answer: 1. An explanation as to why not use `case` in this situation (hint: it's in the documentation) 2. the declaration of `varchar` without length (even though that's a copy from the OP's code, it's still a problem).

Comment: Thanks! The length was indeed copy pasted and I overlooked it. The explanation is now added :)